# RTL captions in XeTeX / polyglossia

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, bidi

I am transitioning to XeTeX for writing Hebrew/English texts. When I have a caption in Hebrew the colon appears on the wrong side of the number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{DavidLibre-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{DavidLibre-Regular}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
בוקר טוב
\caption{אמרתי בוקר טוב}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of caption]

I couldn't find where the figure is defined in the ldf file or style files so I tried

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{:\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

but that just added an additional colon.

While I'm at it, can the polyglossia-defined strings be changed without modifying the ldf file? For example, I tried `\renewcommand{\figurename}{תרשים}` but that had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable XeTeX unicode bidi by using an explicit `Script=Hebrew` for your Hebrew font.

```
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{DavidLibre-Regular}[Script=Hebrew]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!